# Spark Streaming application shutdown when Kafka brokers are restarted

Tags: apache-spark, apache-kafka, hadoop-yarn, spark-streaming

I have spark streaming application that uses direct streaming listening to KAFKA topic.

```
    HashMap<String, String> kafkaParams = new HashMap<String, String>();
    kafkaParams.put("metadata.broker.list", "broker1,broker2,broker3");
    kafkaParams.put("auto.offset.reset", "largest");

    HashSet<String> topicsSet = new HashSet<String>();
    topicsSet.add("Topic1");

    JavaPairInputDStream<String, String> messages = KafkaUtils.createDirectStream(
            jssc, 
            String.class, 
            String.class,
            StringDecoder.class, 
            StringDecoder.class, 
            kafkaParams, 
            topicsSet
    );
```

I notice when i stop/shutdown kafka brokers, my spark application also shutdown.

Here is the spark execution script

```
spark-submit \
--master yarn-cluster \
--files /home/siddiquf/spark/log4j-spark.xml
--conf "spark.driver.extraJavaOptions=-Dlog4j.configuration=log4j-spark.xml" \
--conf "spark.executor.extraJavaOptions=-Dlog4j.configuration=log4j-spark.xml" \
--class com.abc.etl.common.DataProcessor \
myapp.jar
```

Spark job submitted successfully and i can track the application driver and worker/executor nodes.

Everything works fine but only concern if kafka borkers are offline or restarted my application controlled by yarn should not shutdown?

Edit: I have create Spark JIRA for community to respond.
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-14737

Comment: I created this as feature request in spark but it seems like this is the expected behavior. We can follow the discussion in given link on spark Jira. https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-14737